# How can I access UI GameObject from Android?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

In my Unity project, I have a Text UI GameObject nammed myText. I export this to an Android project following this link . I can now open it with Android studio and it compiles and installs on my Android device, fine.

Now, in the Android Java program, I want to change the text displayed by the Unity object nammed myText.

Is it possible?

Regards,

Philippe

Comment: Why do you want to change it from android native code?

Comment: I want to do this software : when I will see a particular target (let's say a 2D Code on a machine in a factory), I want to display information about this machine with a see through glasses (like Epson Moverio BT200). I want to get the information to display from a database so, I think its better to do all the information processing in Java/Android, I don't know the script language of Unity and I don't know if it's possible to do this in Unity.